# Configure sharepoint alerts for users only for items they have created and not for all items in the list

Tags: sharepoint

I understand that I can customize alerts using workflows in addition to the alert settings provided by default in sharepoint. However, I want to send notifications to users only for items they have created. The list will have many users and they need to be notified of changes to only the items created by them and not by other users.

I am using Sharepoint online with Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Flow template when Item created or updated. 
Simple workflow can be created which send an email to Created By or Modified by User.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-flow-for-a-list-or-library-in-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business-a9c3e03b-0654-46af-a254-20252e580d01

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flow to send email alerts to the users who created the list item like below, select the "Created By Email":

[image]